# How can I view large XML files in Chrome?

Tags: xml, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome isn't very good at parsing large XML files. Anything over a few MBs and it really starts to struggle.

Is there a good extension which can help? IE8 is the same and Firefox is much better but I've migrated away to Chrome now so would like to stick with the one browser if possible.

Comment: got a large sample XML file so people can try it out?